# aligning bottom of two tables

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I need to align the bottom of these two tables, and I need to add a brace to each side of the second table.. how can I do that?

```
\begin{figure}[]
 \centering
  \subfloat[]{ 
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
  \hline
  0 & 1\\
  \hline
  2 & 1\\
  3 & 1\\
  4 & 2\\
  5 & 3\\
  4 & 8\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  }  
  \subfloat[]{
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
  \hline
  1 & 2\\
  \hline
  3 & 7\\
  4 & 5\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  }
\end{figure}
```

Any help appreciated,

Ted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know, what kind of braces do you mean. Here is an example with round braces, can also be changed to something else.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \subfloat[]{% 
  \begin{tabular}[b]{cc}
  \hline
  0 & 1\\
  \hline
  2 & 1\\
  3 & 1\\
  4 & 2\\
  5 & 3\\
  4 & 8\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}%
  }  \qquad
  \raisebox{1.2\normalbaselineskip}{$\left\{\rule{0pt}{2.1\normalbaselineskip}\right.$}
  \subfloat[]{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{cc} \hline
  1 & 2\\ \hline
  3 & 7\\
  4 & 5\\\hline
  \end{tabular}%
  }~
  \raisebox{1.2\normalbaselineskip}{$\left\}\rule{0pt}{2.1\normalbaselineskip}\right.$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I mean the regular braces ... this ones { { {

Comment: @Flethuseo: no problem, replace the `\left(` with `\left\{` and the `\left)` with `\left\}`. I did it also in my answer

Comment: It is somewhat difficult to use. I added an alternative solution using `delarray`.

Answer (score 4):

For aliging, use

```
\begin{tabular}[b]{cc}
...
```

instead of

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
```

For braces, use `delarray` package.

[image]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{delarray}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \subfloat[]{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{cc}
  \hline
  0 & 1\\
  \hline
  2 & 1\\
  3 & 1\\
  4 & 2\\
  5 & 3\\
  4 & 8\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}}\qquad
  \subfloat[]{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]\{{cc}\}
  \hline
  1 & 2\\
  \hline
  3 & 7\\
  4 & 5\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```